# Edit nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

I have a problem when I edit a nested model. When I execute the code bellow this create another entry in my WeeklySchedule table.

Example: I want to replace 9 to 10 in Monday.

WeeklySchedule table:

Before edit:

```
weekly_schedule_id: 1 monday: 9
```

After edit:

```
weekly_schedule_id: 1 monday: 9
weekly_schedule_id: 2 monday: 10
```

Code:

Models:

```
class Installation < ActiveRecord::Base
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :weekly_schedule
  belongs_to :weekly_schedule
end

class WeeklySchedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :installation
end
```

Form:

```
 <%= simple_form_for @installation, class: 'form-horizontal' do |f| %>
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :weekly_schedule do |w| %>
        <%= w.time_field :monday %>
      <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def update
 @installation.update(installation_params)
 (...)
end

def edit
 @installation = current_user.installations.find_by(:installation_id => params[:id])
end
```

installation_params:

```
{"x"=>"20",
 "y"=>"21",
"weekly_schedule_attributes"=>{"monday"=>"10"}}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show your whole update method in controller

Comment: Also `installation_params` method

Comment: Also show your `edit` method from the controller. (I'm assuming you got to this form by clicking an "Edit" button and that it routes through the `edit` method.)

Comment: Please post the `installation_params` method from the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you are missing `:id` in the strong parameters for the nested model. Make sure your `installation_params` includes `:id` like the following:

```
def installation_params
  params.require(:installation).permit(..., :weekly_schedule_attributes => [:id, :monday, ...])
end
```